# Error: ip address not working After the giving to nginx

Tags: nginx, django

I am deploying the django app to digitalocean my ip address is not working after the `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/lok`
in nginx .I added to the my nginx is as follows

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/urban/urban.new/run/gunicorn.sock 
fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
   listen 80;

# add here the ip address of your server
# or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
   server_name 139.59.36.32;

   keepalive_timeout 5;
   client_max_body_size 4G;

   access_log /home/urban/urban.new/logs/nginx-access.log;
   error_log /home/urban/urban.new/logs/nginx-error.log;

   location /static/ {
       alias /home/urban/lok/templates/style/static/;
   }

# checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
   location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
  }

  location @proxy_to_app {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For . $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }
}
```

but my ip address is not working.Help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your NGINX vhost config seems OK but you have to change a little parameter config:

also, you have to correct in your Vhost the following line:

```
server_name  YOURDOMAIN
```

If you do have a domain then give it as a placeholder localhost

listen for specific IPs with nginx:

```
listen 139.59.36.32:80 default_server;
```

[see documentation from nginx for more details:](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

The next correction is that you have to copy `/etc/nginx/sites-available/lok` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` or create a symlink then reload nginx:

```
# ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/lok /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
# service nginx reload
```

Background:
by default nginx loads conf files that are stored under sites-enabled/* (if you don't change the nginx. conf)

also, you have to look if the default config exits (on installation by default)
ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/default

if the default config exits, move it to another place so that your vhost config takes control of every request on IP.

Comment: can you help to do it **but you have to copy /etc/nginx/sites-available/lok to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/lok.conf reload the nginx with: nginx -s reload**